# Can I detect 0.8 volt with a relay or something?

Tags: relay

I have this currently[image]
It's the ISD1820 voice recorder and it's working as expected, kind of. 
[image]

I have connected as in the schematic above but I want to turn on a LED when the recorder palays the message.
The obvious would be to connect to the 12 v reed switch, but something is very odd with the play-pin.
A dead wire makes the message play. I mean a wire not connected anywhere just touches the pin, and it plays.
The way it's currently working is when the state of the reed switch (and relay) changes the message plays meaning I can't detect it on the relay (or can I?).
Meaning it plays the message no matter if the relay is open or closed. It's the change that makes it play.

I found out that R4 on the top right of the board has 0 v when nothing is playing, but as the message is played it has 0.8 v.
Is that something I can detect? I don't know of any relay that can get triggered on such low voltage.

Sorry for the tag, I'm still new here and don't yet know what tags to use.

EDIT: Dorian has pointed out that it's not appropriate to simply connect something to the pin.
With that said, let's say add a timer relay that I set the time perfectly on to match the message lenght/time, how can I make it get triggered on the state change of the Reed switch or relay.

Comment: Pin 10 where the resistor is connected is the oscillator input. The 0.8V that you see (I guess you used a simple multimeter) can be an average of a clock signal with high levels higher than 0.8V you might not want to mess with it. The resistor R4 is critical for the play speed and is 100k resistor , not very friendly to connect something else on that input. Maybe something with high impedance (MOSFET or a CMOS gate) but first you have to see the signal with an oscilloscope to see what you are dealing with.

Comment: The datasheet is not giving many details, you have to figure out yourself.

Comment: I thought about that too, if I just can connect something there, but I guess I can't. That means I need to use the reed or relay but I don't understand why the player plays when you touch the pins. It's really frustrating.

Comment: I didn't said you can't but it has to be something with a higher impedance. If you're willing to experiment a bit I'm sure  somebody will find a solution. After looking in the datasheet I see that this is the only way to detect when the player is running.

Comment: @Dorian I understand you said I can, but since I believe it's out of my knowledge. It's to me "I can't" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the chip datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/WinbondElectronics/mXxvwt.pdf) , it's for a different package but the same.

I see that the LED output is sending a pulse at the end of the message. Usually this is used for loop playing but we can use to reset a flip flop at the end of the message. The start can is given by the play button that , inverted, can set the flip flop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSICJm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

CD4044 can be used, the E (enable ) input tied to VCC.

Comment: This looks complex. But I will give it a try to at least understand it and see if it really is as complex as I think. The swtich, is that supposed to represent the relay in my ciricut? And any "CD4044" that I manage to google will do as the latch? I'm a bit confused about the D1 LED. Is that a second LED or is that the LED on the board? Sorry for this. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: @Andreas I've edited the schematic. True , LED and R5 are already onboard. LED output is pin 13 (the one connected with R5), You need R1 ,R3, Q1 ( i put a different one more accessible) and the flip flop.  The power lines of CD4044 are not figured in the picture (VDD and VSS) , connect to VDD and VSS of the board. Ask me for details if some other flip flop is more accessible in your area.

Comment: I'd say that no flip flop is accessible around here. I will have to order from online. This is one model that is avalible on a online store in my country https://www.elfa.se/sv/logikkrets-dil-16-cd4044-texas-instruments-cd4044be/p/17347339 Too bad the shipping is about 25 times more expensive than the flip flop. So If I get this correct I solder off the LED and put the anode on VCC and the cathode to where the cathode previously was? And the wire going to "R" on flip flop is going to be the bottom pin of R5 on the board? Then the rest is just connect it together.

Comment: @Andreas Can be done with nand gates like here: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_1.html , like 74HC00 , CD4011 etc , must be CMOS or HCMOS type, sorry a mitype I edited

Comment: @Andreas No. Just solder a wire from R5 side not connected to LED to R input of the flip flop. Leave the LED alone where it is. I would make a small bredboard with R2, R3 , Q1 and the flip flop then connect to the board with four wires, GND(or VSS is the same) VCC, play input to R2 and LED output pin (where R5 is connected to the chip) to R.

Comment: Sorry about the long delay. What you say sounds like it works, I won't have time or parts to test it now so I will accept the answer on basis that I believe you and I too believe it will work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Andreas Add updates when needed. Thanks. If you find somebody with an oscilloscope take a look at the original signal to. Depending on how it looks it might be a good path to.

Answer (score -1):

The threshold base voltage to turn on a transistor is 0.6V - 0.8V. So I think you can simply use a transistor as a switch.

If the transistor doesn't completely turn on, you can use Darlington Pair. In this technique, you use two transistors to obtain higher amplification of the current of your 0.8V signal (Higher gain).

Relays can't sense small signals like the signal that you would like to detect (0.8V & small current) but transistors can detect them.

If you still want to use relays for isolation reasons or to turn on a high power device or whatever the reason is, you can use the transistors to detect the small signal and the output of the transistor would be the input coil of the relay to turn it on/off. In this case, a free wheeling diode should be used to protect the transistor from the spikes that are caused by discharging the input coil of the relay.

Comment: The input is an oscillator input, it's unlikely to be DC 0.8V see the comment above. It might mess the chip clock. Some different approach must be used. Update the answer accordingly to take back my downvote and read the datasheet before answering please.